# Does traveling one day a week to an alternate facility count as a normal commute?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs

The IRS is clear that your normal commute from home to your usual office is not tax-deductible. But let's say, once every week, I have have to travel directly to an alternate office, start my workday there, and then return home. Not that it necessarily matters, but this alternate office is much further from my home than my main office.

Is my commute to this alternate office every week deductible?

Comment: If you are traveling _directly_ to the other office from home and returning home directly, then I think the answer is No, but if you stop by the usual office on the way to the alternate office, I think the answer is Yes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I'm almost certain that is wrong.

Comment: Actually I'm not that certain. But it may be partially wrong  :O

Comment: Is the alternate office in the same metropolitan area as your home?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a no. What about this: I work as network technician in the Vegas. Once per week I need to do server maintenance in LA, and I spend a long day driving. You tell me that is not a business trip? Yeah, have fun. My normal place of work is in Vegas somewhere - 9 out of 10 days, as per the OP. I do not go there because - heck, it is a long trip already, iirc more than 8 hours on the road. So, I go directly. Main question is:why is this even a question - self employed? Because for an employed person, I would expect the employer to pay up per trip regulations.

Answer (score 2):

1. To begin with, are you self-employed?  In the US, I'm almost certain "normal" non-self-employed people can *not* deduct business travel *at all*.  (Your employer would be paying the costs of it.) And not any form of commuting. So it's No all the way down.
2. If you are self-employed.  In my opinion, yes, it's a deduction.  I'm guessing you probably *can not* get away with saying your home is your principal place of business, but, given that, the "unusual" office you go to occasionally is a worksite trip - and it's a normal expense (ie, a deduction). No mystery, straightforward.

{If your *principal place of business* was indeed your home office, not that company office, you could charge ALL travel - but that's like saying "If you could make-up fake receipts and charge them, you could charge them!"}